# Javascript: Sum of natural numbers--- Reference Error: Not Defined

Tags: javascript, referenceerror

I wrote this code and it says that t1 is not defined. "t1" is the name of my text box. I read somewhere that it could be the problem of local and global variables because other functions were also using "t1". so i declared the variable outside the function so as to make it global but it didn't help either ways. At first, "t2" was posing the same problem but making it global, the error was removed.

```
<head>    
<script language="javascript">
    var x=parseInt(t1.value);
    function nn()
    {

        var i=1;
        var s=0;
        while (i<=x)
            {
            s=s+i;
            i++;
            }

    }
t2.value=s;
</script>
</head>
<body>
Enter A Number : 
<input type=text size=20 name="t1">
<input type=button onclick="nn()" value="Sum of Natural Numbers">
<br>
Sum Obtained : 
<input type=text size=20 name="t2">
</body>
```

Please explain in simple words. I have very little coding knowledge.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

you cant access textboxes in javascript by simply saying `t1` or `t2`.you have to get the reference of the element and then you should access the value property of that element.

give some id to the text box and the access it using `document.getElementById()` method.see the snippet below

```js
function nn() {
  var x = parseInt(document.getElementById('t1').value);
  var i = 1;
  var s = 0;
  while (i <= x) {
    s = s + i;
    i++;
  }
  document.getElementById('t2').value = s;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  Enter A Number :
  <input type=text size=20 name="t1" id='t1'>
  <input type=button onclick="nn()" value="Sum of Natural Numbers">
  <br>Sum Obtained :
  <input type=text size=20 name="t2" id='t2'>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code t1.value does not exist. T1 is a DOM element, not a JavaScript variable.

You should put an id tag on the textbox like this:

```
<input type=text size=20 name="t1" id=”t1”>
```

Then adjust your javascript like this :

```
var x=parseInt(document.getElementById('t1').value);
```

Also, your code will not work, as it is executed before textbox is generated on the page.

To prevent it you can use document.ready event.

or like comment from  T.J. Crowder suggests :

put the script underneath the elements it references

Comment: **And** put the script underneath the elements it references, ideally just before the closing `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass to javascript the object related with textbox t1 and t2, in order to handle both input and output data.
First, change the html code into

```
<input type=text size=20 id="t1">
<input type=text size=20 id="t2">
<input type=button onclick="javascript:nn();" value="Sum of Natural Numbers">
```

Then move to upper Javascript block and write this code

```
var t1 = document.getElementById("t1");
var t2 = document.getElementById("t2");
var x=parseInt(t1.value,10);
```

The rest of the code follows.
Happy coding !

Answer (score 1):

t1 variable you have not defined change your HTML as

```
<input type=text size=20 name="t1" id="t1">
```

from this id you can get this element in Javascript like below

```
var x=parseInt(document.getElementById('t1').value);
```

write the function below body tag to run the script properly

Answer (score 0):

Put this code under `</body>`:

```
<script language="javascript">
var x=parseInt(t1.value);
function nn()
{

    var i=1;
    var s=0;
    while (i<=x)
        {
        s=s+i;
        i++;
        }

}
```

t2.value=s;

When the first line of your code executed, this element is not loaded yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Updateed Code.

```html
<head>    
<script language="javascript">
    
    function nn()
    {
     var t1 = document.getElementById('t1'); 
    var x=parseInt(t1.value);

        var i=1;
        var s=0;
        while (i<=x)
            {
            s=s+i;
            i++;
            }
 var t2 = document.getElementById('t2'); 
     t2.value=s;
 
    }

</script>
</head>
<body>
Enter A Number : 
<input type=text size=20 name="t1" id="t1">
<input type=button onclick="nn()" value="Sum of Natural Numbers" >
<br>
Sum Obtained : 
<input type=text size=20 name="t2" id="t2">
</body>
```